# Are the following proofs correct(2)?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

A list of some questions from class and my attempt at them are given below. Would appreciate any advice on what I did wrong or on how to attempt some of the questions.

> 3. Let A: X → Y be a linear operator from a linear space X to a linear space Y. Show that the image of a linear operator A: X → Y is a linear subspace of Y.

My attempt:

1.Showing non empty, I don't know any examples..

2.Showing additive, where $y_1, y_2 \in \ker(A):$

> $Ax_1 = y_1$ and $Ax_2 = y_2$
>
> $A(x_1 + x_2) = y_1 + y_2$

3.Showing scalar multiplication for $a \in F$

> $a(Ax_1)=ay_1$
>
> $ay_1 = ay_1$

_

> 4.(a) The differentiation operator $D : C^∞ → C^∞$ is a linear operator. Find the kernel and
>   image of D. (b) The operator $D^n
> : C^∞ → C^∞$ is a linear operator (differentiation n times).
>   Find the kernel and image of $D^n$
>   .

My attempt:

(a) ker(D) = c, c ∈ F and im(D) = $C^∞$ , I don't know how to prove that this is the case it just seems like it is such.

(b) ker($D^n$) = $x^n$, x ∈ $C^∞$ and im($D^n$) = $C^∞$ , I don't know how to prove that this is the case it just seems like it is such.

Comment: As in the case of $D^n$ it would be span of all polynomials degree $\leq n$.

Comment: Great thanks @Panchal Shamsundar

Comment: And for kernel use "0" of the vector space as image elements instead of using $y_1$ $y_2$, also in my previous comment there is an error as the kernel is span of polynomials of degree $\leq n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

3.1:  See problem 1.

4(a):  It is a [standard](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Zero_Derivative_implies_Constant_Function) application of the mean value theorem that $Df = 0$ implies $f$ is constant.

4(b):  Your kernel is incorrect.  What can you say about *all* polynomials of degree $<n$?  For the image, what is the definition of $C^\infty$?